# display a different name from the 'real' URL name

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to change an incoming http request

- for `www.pathfinder.com/T/client/care/login.html`
- to look like `www.Theshop/care/login.html`

in the "URL" line on the browser.

How can this be done with using "URL" re-write?

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^www.pathfinder.com/T/clients/care/$" "www.Theshop.com/care/"
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://serverfault.com/questions/650474/how-to-get-hostname-into-rewriterule seems like a good place to start

Comment: RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^www.pathfinder.com/TMAS/clients/care/$" "lightwaytechnologiesapps.com/"

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "^www\.pathfinder.com/TMAS/clients/care/$" [NC]
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "lightwaytechnologiesapps" [L,R,NE]

Comment: You can (and should) edit the question directly actually. Please check my edit and maybe also make sure your rules actually match the example you've given.

Comment: The rewrite rules you've tried don't match your requirements. You've asked to rewrite `pathfinder.com/T/...` but your rules expect `www.pathfinder.com/TMAS/...`. They're not the same.

Comment: Why do you think mod_rewrite can do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/t/client/(care/.*)$ http://www.theshop.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

This will redirect
    `http://www.pathfinder.com/T/client/care/foo.html`
or `http://pathfinder.com/T/client/care/foo.html`
to `http://theshop.com/care/foo.html`

using flags

- [NC|nocase](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)
- [R|redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)
- [L|last](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

If you only want to redirect the login page use

```
RewriteRule ^/t/client(/care/login.html)$ http://www.theshop.com$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: thanks! I do not want to redirect to another page; i only want to change the displayed name in the browser window and stay on the same page.

Comment: You can only change the URL by redirecting or using javascript (`window.location.href="http://www.theshop.com";`) or using a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=http://www.theshop.com/">`-tag which will also reload the page. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: just want to replace the displayed url(which is a long path name) with something simple that someone can remember (not short url) not a new url somewhere else. This can not be done with rewrite?

Comment: This is what `mod_rewrite` does. It changes one URL to another and the request is redirected (or proxied) to the new location. If the new URL points to the same host or not is up to you. Remove `http://www.theshop.com` from the rule and you'll stay on the same server.

Comment: ok i added that ; and when i open the old page; nothing changes.

Comment: @johnWoodsmall Run `apachectl configtest`, restart apache with `service apache2 restart`, clear browser cache and inspect the access.log with `tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log` while you reload the page.